# multiple category_ids breaking in CSV

Tags: magento-1.9, csv

If you have 2 categories a product needs to be in and the category is over 100 - you get a value that looks like this **"100,101"**

The problem is excel automatically reads this as a number and you cant change it so when you update the CSV it breaks.

**Does anyone know how to solve this issue?**

Comment: Use a proper CSV editor like OpenOffice Calc

Answer (score 0):

You can do following for your problem

1) add single quote .

2) add your comma separated category ids

3) add end single quote.

this thing works for me in windows machine

Hope this will help you

Comment: Is my answer help you?